# how to insert a var to string(char*)

Tags: c++, string

ive code

```
if(argv[1] == flags[1]) {
    BDsorts* temp = new BDsorts();
    temp->openBd("temp.bd\0");
    int max_size = 1000;
    void(*sorts[4])(std::vector<int>&) = {bubble_sort,insertion_sort, selection_sort,counting_sort};
    char* sort_name[4]{"bubble_sort", "insertion_sort", "selection_sort", "counting_sort"};
    std::vector<int> ar(max_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { 
        if(sorts[i] == nullptr) { continue; }
        randomAr(ar, max_size);
        int time = sortTime(sorts[i], ar);
        add_data("INSERT INTO ReSorts (idSort, idSizeAr, durSort_ms) VALUES(1, 2, 3);");
    }
    temp.closeBd();
}
```

in string "add_data("INSERT INTO ReSorts (idSort, idSizeAr, durSort_ms) VALUES(1, 2, 3);");"
I need to replace "VALUES(1, 2, 3);" with "VALUES(value of i, value of max_size, value of time)"

how can i do it?

tried to use concatenation and interpolation, as in c#

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using c style strings rather than C++'s std::string? The two are handled differently and the c-style approach is lower level and less recommended in modern C++. (It is also less like C# string handling, though neither is the same.)

Comment: Have you tried `std::ostringstream`?  `std::ostringstream insert_stream; insert_stream << "INSERT INTO ReSorts (idSort, idSizeAr, durSort_ms) Values(" << value1 << ", " << value2 << ", " << value3 << ");"; add_data(insert_stream.str());`

Comment: I transfer const char * to the add_data () function

Comment: Unrelated: `temp.closeBd();` probably should be `temp->closeBd();` and it looks like `temp` has been [leaked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: [Did you remember to include the proper header, sstream?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

Comment: Unrelated: `char* sort_name[4]{"bubble_sort", "insertion_sort", "selection_sort", "counting_sort"};` won't compile on modern compilers. It's allowing a non-`const` pointer to point at `const` data ([string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)). This can blow up at runtime in strange ways if the compiler allows it, so the smart compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: i know it. but i cant use type std::string

Comment: When an instructor says "You can't use X" often what they are really saying is "Top grades go to the students who solve the problem by writing their own version of X". That doesn't seem to be the case here, though.

Comment: Since use of std::string is proscribed, look into using [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). And to provide memory for the c style string, you might consider managing it with std::vector<char> or std::unique_ptr<char[]>

Comment: If you're willing to modify the string literal a bit, [`std::format("INSERT INTO ReSorts (idSort, idSizeAr, durSort_ms) VALUES({}, {}, {});", i, max_size, time)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) could be used...